# What does the * do with that class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

It might be a "dumb" question but i dont know what * do in that code.

```
ClassA* classa;
```

ClassA is a class, so what does the * actually do with a class? and how this ?operator? called?

Comment: [The definitive C++ book guide and list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: This question would be better answered by reading an introductory book to C++ rather than an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is for pointer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` does not do anything with a class, it changes the type of the declared variable by making it a pointer:

```
ClassA *classa; // classa is a pointer to ClassA
```

You can add multiple asterisks to make pointers to pointers, pointers to pointers to pointers, and so on:

```
ClassA **classa; // classa is a pointer to pointer to ClassA
ClassA ***classa; // classa is a pointer to pointer to pointer to ClassA
```

Note that when the same asterisk is used in an expression (as opposed to a declaration) it "reduces" the level of a pointer, so

```
ClassA *classa;
foo(*classa); // Dereferences the pointer, producing ClassA
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight!
Thanks for your answer, now i got it!

Answer (score 0):

Pointer declaration.

After this declaration, `classa` is a variable with type *"Pointer-to-a-ClassA object"*.   It can point to any `ClassA` object, or any object that inherits from `ClassA`